# Log in user and send him to profile page if username and password match database, else console.log("error")

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, body-parser

Need to do this homework where a user inputs his username and password and if it matches database will send user to profile page where it says "Hello <%= user.username %>, Can't seem to get it to work, it always stays in the same page but gets the user information from the database.

The earlier version worked and sent the user to the profile page, but even if the inputs were wrong it still sent him so obviously I tried preventing that.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const connection = require("./connect");

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.set("view engine", "ejs");


// DB
connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.log("Database connected!");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");

});

app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
    console.log(user);
    res.render("profile", { user })
})

app.post("/", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
    user = await queryFunction("select * from users where users.username = " + connection.escape(req.body.username) +
        " and users.password = " + connection.escape(req.body.password));
    console.log(user)
    if (req.body.username === user.username && req.body.password === user.password) return res.redirect("/profile") 
    else console.log("Something went wrong!")
});


async function queryFunction(queryString) {
    let results = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => connection.query(queryString, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
        else {
            resolve(results);
        }

    }))
    return results;
};
```

Comment: I dont get this .... How Your `get` request can know which user data to return ?, the user loaded during the `post` request isint in this same scope mate.

Comment: Ok that aside because I see that know but now I'm focused on the problem I asked. I will fix that later.

Comment: You must provide some kind of `session` or other auth mechanism, to link the incomming requests together.

Comment: You should find a good tutorial if you want to learn node.js and express. You are doing a couple of big no-nos. You never ever want to store passwords in the database. That's probably the #1 thing on any security checklist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `express-session` package to track user session. This example uses `MemoryStore` as default.

Note:

> The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.

You could use `db` to store your session. There are various connector available depending on `db` type. More about session and db connectors [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html)

```
var session = require('express-session')

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))

app.post("/", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
  ...
  if (req.body.username === user.username && req.body.password === user.password) {
    // you can then set some variable to session to track login status
    res.session.loggedin = true
    return res.redirect("/profile")
  }
  else console.log("Something went wrong!")
});
```

Elsewhere, you could, for example

```
app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.loggedin) {
    res.render("login");
  } else {
    console.log(user);
    res.render("profile", { user })
  }
})
```